# Grails: Parsing through JSON String using JSONArray/JSONObject

Tags: json, grails

I have the below JSON string coming in as a request parameter into my grails controller.

```
{
    "loginName":"user1",
    "timesheetList":
    [
        {
            "periodBegin":"2014/10/12",
            "periodEnd":"2014/10/18",
            "timesheetRows":[
                {
                    "task":"Cleaning",
                    "description":"cleaning description",
                    "paycode":"payCode1"
                },
                {
                    "task":"painting",
                    "activityDescription":"painting description",
                    "paycode":"payCode2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "overallStatus":"SUCCESS"
}
```

As you can see, the timesheetList might have multiple elements in it. In this ( above ) case, we have only one. So, I expect it to behave like an Array/List.

Then I had the below code to parse through it:

```
String saveJSON // This holds the above JSON string.

def jsonObject = grails.converters.JSON.parse(saveJSON) // No problem here. Returns a JSONObject. I checked the class type.
def jsonArray = jsonArray.timesheetList // No problem here. Returns a JSONArray. I checked the class type.
println "*** Size of jsonArray1: " + jsonArray1.size() // Returns size 1. It seemed fine as the above JSON string had only one timesheet in timesheetList

def timesheet1 = jsonArray[1] // This throws the JSONException, JSONArray[1] not found. I tried jsonArray.getJSONObject(1) and that throws the same exception.
```

Basically, I am looking to seamlessly iterate through the JSON string now. Any help?

Comment: Any justification for the -1? Is the question too basic? Or if you know of some resource online which gives a decent and neat sample example of using JSONObject/JSONArray that would have helped. I did google it out though.

Answer (score 0):

1st off to simplify your code, use `request.JSON`. Then `request.JSON.list[ 0 ]` should be working